# Wrong Output while finding the root of the equation in C

Tags: c, math

The following is the C code for calculating the roots of an equation using the Newton-Raphson Algorithm:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

double function(double x);
double derivative(double x);

int main(){
    double guess=3;
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        double val=function(guess);
        double d=derivative(guess);
        guess=guess-val/d;
        if(abs(function(guess))<0.00005){
            printf("%lf",guess);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

double function(double x){
    return pow(x,5)+2;  //f(x)=x^5+2
}

double derivative(double x){
    double h=0.00001;
    return (function(x+h)-function(x))/h;
}
```

But the output after compilation is `-1.208869`, which actually does not satisfy the condition that abs(f(x))<0.00005. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are printing `x=guess`, the break condition checks `f(x)=function(guess)`. https://godbolt.org/z/raff6jvP1

Comment: @rturrado Your Compiler Explorer link appears to be using C++, which may pull in the appropriate overload for `std::abs(double x)`. In C, `abs` **always** returns an `int`.

Comment: btw naming a function `function` is a bad idea

Comment: @AdrianMole You're right! I thought Devvrat Chaubal was expecting the value printed to be smaller than 0.00005. My mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `abs(function(guess))` call returns an **integer** value ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/abs)), which will be truncated to zero if the value is less than 1 (as it is when your program stops).

What you need is the [fabs() function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fabs), to return the absolute value of its given argument as a `double`.

Changing your `if` block to use this will work:

```c
        if (fabs(function(guess)) < 0.00005) { // Use "fabs" ... not "abs"
            printf("%lf", guess);
            break;
        }
```